# Merging 1 Column with multiple rows per row label

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, merge

I have a pivot table that has different columns. First column is Part Numbers, next column is part name.
There are a random number of lines for each Part Number

I copy and paste this into another sheet so I can use it like a standard table

Is there a way to center the Part name across all the part number lines without going by each part number individually?

I can't use format painter since each part number is a different # of lines.

Comment: Could you provide a sample about this problem? Try this method: right click PivotTable- select **PivotTable Option**...- **Display** tab- check the option **Classic PivotTbale layout (enables dragging of fields in the grid)**

Answer (score 0):

Put your cursor in the pivot table then go to the ribbon and use Design>Layout>Report Layout>Repeat Item Labels:

[image]

Ensure that you are also using "Show in Tabular Form" from the same menu.